# Discord.py REWRITE - How to make a Guild Invite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, invite

I am trying to make my bot create an invite

```
invite = await bot.create_invite()
```

This gives an error `'bot' object has no Attribute 'create_invite'`
I am using the Discord.py Rewrite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify what you're making the invite for, because the bot doesn't currently have a target for the invite:

```py
@bot.command()
async def createinv(ctx):
    invite = ctx.channel.create_invite()
    await ctx.send(f"Here's your invite: {invite}")
```

---

**References:**

- [`TextChannel.create_invite()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_invite)
- [`abc.GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) - The general target that's needed

Answer (score 1):

Use [`channel.create_invite()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite).

Example:

```py
invite = await message.channel.create_invite()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    await ctx.send(f"Your invite is {invite}")
```